# How to make IBM MQ preference one host in a CCDT file containing multiple hosts

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I was given a CCDT file containing multiple addresses (IP + port).  Some of those are reachable and some are not.  I want to never attempt a connection to the unreachable ones.  How can I do that in Java?

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
cf.setCCDTURL(ccdt);
cf.removeConnection(3); <-- NEED SOMETHING THAT DOES THIS
```

I would rather not edit the CCDT file.

Some of the connections are for DR and not always up.  I want to preference the ones that ARE up for connection attempts first.

Comment: Are you sure they are not available sometimes? For example disaster recovery?  Why do you want to prevent it from attempting to connect to those?

Comment: What you are asking about is not possible from the IBM MQ classes for JMS API.  The only option would be to use a tool such as `runmqsc -n` to delete channels you do not want from the CCDT.  If as I mentioned above those that are no reachable are really DR or something similar, then likely a better suggestion is to tune your connect timeout to a lower value so they fail quickly and move on to the next.  Also note that depending on the settings you can provide values that give some CLNTCONN channels more weight than others.  Best to answer your question with more details on what you need.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  You're right, they are for DR and normally down.  If I can give more weigh to the ones that are up so they're hit first, that's great.  In my CCDT I have CONNAME containing 4 connections.  Can I adjust the weight on those somehow?

Comment: You can only order then in the order you like, MQ will attempt to connect from left to right.  You could split them out to different channels and use the weighting feature, but since the channel name is the same you would need to use MQ v9.2 and JSON based CCDT feature, binary CCDT can only have one entry per channel name, JSON relaxed this restriction. You can also Programmatically specify the connectivity details and bypass the CCDT if you want more control.

Comment: I think tuning connect timeout down and re-ordering the CONNAME to be in the preferred order is probably the simplest.  If the destination does site switches periodically (vs just a short DR test) then having two copies of the CCDT to use depending on the site could also be an option as well, it would still have the 2nd site IPs included at the end of the list, but if they switch sites you could sub in the other copy of the CCDT which would have the current sites IPs preferred.